# Sharing a CiviCRM database across multiple sites hosted on Aegir

Tags: multisite, aegir

I know it is possible to have multiple sites using the same Civi database which I'd really like to do, but our sites use the Aegir hosting system and so I'm not sure this will be possible?

Thanks!

Aiden

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you'd want to do this? Sounds like a bad idea for most cases.

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment Alan! Basically the sites represent different spheres of the same organisation but we'd like all the CiviCRM related data to be shared between.

Comment: Aiden's comment transferred from an answer - Not enough reputation to comment Alan! Basically the sites represent different spheres of the same organisation but we'd like all the CiviCRM related data to be shared between.